# Angular2 ActivatedRoute In Root Component

Tags: angular, typescript, router

My root component has a breadcrumb. The breadcrumb needs three things from the ActivatedRoute: path, params and data. This should be strait forward and in fact it works without a hitch when inside the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` as soon as I move it outside of the outlet into the root component (Because every page will have it) The ActivatedRoute no longer triggers the observers.

Does any one know how to either use the ActivatedRoute outside of the outlet or know of an alternative to access the path, params and data of the route?

Comment: You can put data you need in a service/store/event emitter from routed component and use it in your app component from there, for example

Comment: @Sasxa Then I have to add that to every component that needs to update the breadcrumb (12 pages) which is a lot of repetitive code and not a good solution.

Comment: You can make base component that does this and extend it in your page components. Works quite well in Angular 2.3+

Comment: @ZaksBack would injecting your component with a Router instead, and subscribing to `router.events` be better for you?